# Checking for permission at runtime is failing even though I have said permission defined in the manifest

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-ndk

I have defined the following permission in my the manifest of RecSched application/project:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.recschedapk"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
    <permission android:name="com.example.recschedapk.permission.DEADLY_ACT"
        android:label="DeadlyActivity"
        android:description="@string/permdesc"
        android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.COST_MONEY"
        android:protectionLevel="dangerous" />
        :
        :
</manifest>
```

I have specified this permission in the other application(project) of WebApp:

```
<uses-permissiom android:name="com.example.recschedapk.permission.DEADLY_ACT" />
```

In the WebApp.java file I have the following function defined to check for permission at runtime:

```
private boolean checkPermission()
    {

        String permission = "com.example.recschedapk.permission.DEADLY_ACT";
        int res = getBaseContext().checkCallingOrSelfPermission(permission);
        Log.d("PERMCHECK", "int val : "+ res);
        return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);            
    }
```

The call for the above function :

```
               if((this.checkPermission())
        return new VideoBroadCastObject(this);
```

The call seems to be failing no matter what. New to android here. Can anybody tell me what the problem here is??

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> if you are not currently processing an IPC, this function will always fail.

The other app does not owns/declares this permission, that leaves the only condition that the code that is executing `checkPermission()` must belong to a process/pid which has been granted this permission. That means `checkPermission()` must be executed from an IPC call. That is, an `IBinder` you received from the other process calls this.

Comment: If you don't mind can you elaborate a bit, maybe with an example please. How should I be using the IBinder?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your process flow is but you can try this...

```
private boolean checkPermission() {
    String permission = "com.example.recschedapk.permission.DEADLY_ACT";
    int res = getBaseContext().checkPermission(permission, Binder.getCallingPid(), Binder.getCallingUid());
    Log.d("PERMCHECK", "int val : "+ res);
    return (res == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED);            
}
```